# Redirect to Login page (Private Route) is not working | React Router | React js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new in React js. I want to Redirect user if not logged in to Login Page.
Here is my code:

PrivateRoute.js File

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({ login, component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  console.log(login);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={(props) =>
          !login ? <Redirect to="/signin" /> : <Component {...props} />
        }
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

App.js File

```js
const [login, setlogin] = useState(false);

 const isLoggedIn = (status) => {
    setlogin(status);
    
  };

return (
<Switch>
        <PrivateRoute login={login} exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </PrivateRoute>
        
        <Route path="/signin">
          <Login isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} token={(t) => setToken(t)}/>
        </Route>
       
        <PrivateRoute path="/categories">
          <Categories />
        </PrivateRoute>
       
</Switch
)
```

Can anyone find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any errors or is the functionality different than expected?

is this working?

Suggestion 2:

in the App.js file

```
<PrivateRoute login={login} exact path="/" component ={Home}>
```

Then,

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ login, component: Component, ...rest }) => { 
console.log(login);
 return !login ? <Redirect to="/signin" /> :<Route {...rest} component ={Component} /> 
};
```

Suggestion 3:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ login, component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  console.log(login);
  return (!login ? <Redirect to="/signin" /> : 
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={(props) =>
          <Component {...props} />
        }
      />
  );
};
```

Comment: No errors, Just not redirecting to Login Page

Comment: Can you directly access the `/signin` route? is that working fine?

Comment: Yes, It works fine, All other Routes are also working but not redirecting.

Comment: I have edited the answer, Unfortunately, I can't run this code. Can you check if it is working?

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, can you remove the `{...props}` from the `<Component/>` and see if there is any improvement?

Comment: It's redirecting to the login page , but after login when I click on Home, Error Occured

Comment: Can you try the third suggestion then? Also what was the error?

Comment: I tried your code first it shows error Props is not defined When I remove {...props} Redirecting is working fine but after login when I click on Home, Error Occured

Comment: I edited my answer with two other suggestions , can you try implementing the third suggestion ?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your answer 2 and 3 both are working and also Home page is working.                                                                                                  
        <PrivateRoute path="/categories">
          <Categories />
        </PrivateRoute>                                                                                                  But this route shows undefined

Comment: Good to know. I will clean up the answer to display only 2 and 3

Comment: I tried this for Categories :                                                                                                      <PrivateRoute path="/categories" component={Categories} />                                                  But it still shows undefined.

Comment: Can you try categories with suggestion 3

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ login, component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return login ? (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => <Component {...props} />} />
  ) : <Redirect to="/signin" />
}
```